# C++ Антивирусник не дает скачивать файлы

Tags: c++, файлы, winapi, download

Имеется программа которая просто скачивает файл и записывает на рабочий стол, все хорошо программа скачивает, но вот в чем проблема антивирусник при виде сего чуда не пропускает трафик. Антивирусники которые пробовал: Eset Nod32, Avast.

Сам код:

```
HRESULT hr;
LPCTSTR Url = _T("Ссылка"), File = _T("C:\\Users\Пользователь\\Desktop");
hr = URLDownloadToFile(0, Url, File, 0, 0);
```

Я конечно понимаю, что данный вопрос не очень относится к теме данного форума но, есть ли какой нибудь другой код для скачки файла, чтобы антивирусник не ругался?

Comment: Если `Url` и `File` получаются динамически, антивирус тоже ругается? Потому как антивирусники вполне могут отслеживать именно такую конструкцию, т.к. обычно пути к файлам либо относительные, либо формируются динамически.

Comment: Ещё возможно будет полезна [эта](https://kaimi.io/2011/11/antivirus-trolling/) статья.

Comment: Да пути формируются динамически т.к это необходимо программе. Тоесть если я буду указывать не такой путь: "C:\\Users\Пользователь\\Desktop", а к примеру такой "C:/Users/Пользователь/Desktop" то должно сработать?

Comment: @Aleksei.C, нет. Я имел ввиду, что если путь, например, вводится с клавиатуры - это нормально, а когда абсолютный путь задан в самом коде программы - это действительно подозрительно. С относительными путями понятно - они полезны, а абсолютный путь - нет. Но судя по всему тут проблема именно в URLDownloadToFile или в следующих за ней функциях.

Comment: Хорошо я понял, если я попоробую изменить функцию URLDownloadToFile на функцию из библеотеки curl это сможет помочь? И еще такой момент я несколько раз проверял свой скомпилированный файл антивирусниками и на вт заливал, но не один антивирус не показывал что файл заражен.

Comment: В подобных случаях лучше сразу писать в саппорт "чуда" и спросить. Вполне может оказаться  false positive и они пофиксят базы. Или самоудалятся

Comment: Почему `File` ссылается на каталог, а не на файл?

Comment: Здесь ошибка не большая в коде, но так все работает.